# Error opening a 2013 template workflow for Sharepoint Online site using designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

When I try to open one of my SPO site 2013 template based workflow in SPD, I am getting error as "Server side activities have been updated you need to restart SharePoint designer".

I can open 2010 template workflow, error occurs only for 2013 template based workflow.

Already tried clearing cache and website data, but it didn't helped.

Please let me know if you have any sugesstion/idea on who to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue, to resolve this issue we need to update the SharePoint designer and to do so we have to follow this steps : 
    1. Check whether the Microsoft SharePoint 2013 service pack 1 is installed or not in system. If not Please download it and install from URL mentioned below         · For 64 bit system download service pack from here
          https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42009
        · For 32 bit system download service pack from here
          https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42015
    2. Download the update provided by Microsoft for SP designer 13. Download it from this link
    · https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114337
    3. Restart SharePoint Designer.

I tried and it worked for me !!!